# Is it necessary to pass the indices as arguments while doing mergesort?

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I see that many implementations of mergesort I see online, such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ pass in arguments l, m, and r to know where the sub arrays start and end. I was wondering if the runtime and space complexity would remain the same if we instead made copies of the sub arrays and passed those in. Sample suggested code is as follows:

```
class Solution {

    //mergeSort implementation
    public int[] sortArray(int[] nums) {

        if (nums.length == 1) {
            return nums;
        }

        int arrayLength = nums.length;

        // make copies instead of passing indices
        int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 0, arrayLength/2);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, arrayLength/2, arrayLength);

        left = sortArray(left);
        right = sortArray(right);

        return merge(left, right);

    }

    public int[] merge(int[] left,int[] right) {

        int[] merged = new int[left.length + right.length];

        int mergedCounter = 0;
        int i = 0; //leftCounter
        int j = 0; //rightCounter
        while (mergedCounter != left.length + right.length) {
            if (i == left.length) {
                merged[mergedCounter] = right[j];
                mergedCounter++;
                j++;
            } else if (j == right.length) {
                merged[mergedCounter] = left[i];
                mergedCounter++;
                i++;
            } else {
                if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
                    merged[mergedCounter] = left[i];
                    mergedCounter++;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    merged[mergedCounter] = right[j];
                    mergedCounter++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        return merged;

    }

}
```

I believe the run complexity is not increased, because making a copy takes the same run time as initializing an n-length new array via new int[n]. This part of the problem also includes an O(n) merge subfunction so it wouldn't matter.

I also believe that the space complexity stays the same. While we are creating two temporary subarrays in the recursive call, the same amount of space would be created in the merge step as specified in online solutions using pointers to l, m, and r.

Is my thought process valid, or am I missing something?

Comment: `I believe the run [time] complexity is not increased` the *asymptotic* complexity may stay the same while constant factors differ widely. `am I missing something` maintainability/readability, for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any additional copy operations will increase running time. Making copies of sub-arrays will increase space requirements by a constant, but since "complexity" ignores constants and/or lower order terms, space "complexity" will remain the same.

Most libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort, where indices (or pointers) are updated on the fly, not passed via recursion, and are usually kept in registers based on compiler optimization. Top down merge sort is mostly used as a learning exercise.

Copy operations can be minimized by changing the direction of merge based on merge pass for bottom up merge sort, or based on level of recursion for top down merge sort.

With C / C++, an alternative to passing array and index is to pass a pointer or iterator, reducing the number of parameters needed for each call by 1 parameter.